# Multiple Variables for "-name" parameter in "New-Item"

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm having issues with the following PS script:

```
New-Item -name $InfoLog -path $LogPath -Name ("Info Log - ",$DateStamp," - ",$TimeStamp) -type file
```

It gives me the error-

> Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Name' is specified more than
>   once. To provide  multiple values to parameters that can accept
>   multiple values, use the array syntax.  For example, "-parameter
>   value1,value2,value3".

Any ideas? I also tried it without the parentheses.

Comment: Does "New-Item" only accept one parameter for name? If so how can I make it so I can write out a file with the date and time as well as a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All PowerShell cmdlets accept only one argument per parameter.  However, you passed two arguments to the `-Name` parameter of `New-Item`:

```powershell
New-Item -name $InfoLog -path $LogPath -Name ("Info Log - ",$DateStamp," - ",$TimeStamp) -type file
# One argument ^^^^^^^^     Another argument ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because this is an illegal function call, PowerShell is raising your error.

---

It looks like you meant to write this:

```powershell
New-Item -Path $LogPath -Name "Info Log - $DateStamp - $TimeStamp" -Type File
```

The variables in the string `"Info Log - $DateStamp - $TimeStamp"` will be expanded into the values that they represent:

```powershell
PS > $a = 123   
PS > $b = "abc"
PS > "$a -- $b"
123 -- abc

PS >
```

Comment: Ah! What a dumb mistake! Can't believe I missed that. Thank you, sorry for the waste of time.

I have to wait 5 mins to give you the correct answer.